i am providing src to Image tag by array of object but it is showing blank page rather showing images . have i done anything wrong here?
import React from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import "./work.scss"

function Work() {
    const workObject = [
        {
            path: "/work/1.webp",
            desc:"Maccabi Tzair"
        },
        {
            path: "/work/2.webp",
            desc:"Maccabi Tzair"
        },
        {
            path: "/work/3.webp",
            desc:"Maccabi Tzair"
        },
        {
            path: "/work/4.webp",
            desc:"Maccabi Tzair"
        },
        {
            path: "/work/6.webp",
            desc:"Maccabi Tzair"
        },
        {
            path: "/work/7.webp",
            desc:"Maccabi Tzair"
        },
        {
            path: "/work/1.webp",
            desc:"Maccabi Tzair"
        },
    ]
  return (
      <div className='content'>
          {workObject.map((obj) => {
           <Image src={obj.path} alt='' height={500} width={400}/>
       })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Work

i am providing src to Image tag by array of object but it is showing blank page rather showing images . have i done anything wrong here?please help i am trying it from an hour now
i am using next'js to build a image container it'll show on button clicked

You're not returning anything inside the map function. You need to explicitly return the Image component:
{workObject.map((obj, index) => (
    <Image key={index} src={obj.path} alt='' height={500} width={400} />
))}

or
{workObject.map((obj, index) => {
    return (
        <Image key={index} src={obj.path} alt='' height={500} width={400} />
    )
})}

Btw, it's not a good idea to use index as a key, here it's just for example
